# Redshift : Query Optimisation

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Need help in optimizing the below query. Please suggest here

Db : Redshift

Sort Key:

```
      order Table : install_ts

      order_item: Install_ts

      Suborder. : install_ts

      suborder_item: install_ts
```

Dist Key: Not Added

query: Extracting selected columns from below table (not all)

```
    select *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY oo.id,
                                 oi.id
                    ORDER BY i.suborder_id DESC) AS suborder_rank,
    FROM order_item oi
    LEFT JOIN order oo ON oo.id=oi.order_id
    LEFT JOIN sub_order_item i ON i.order_item_id = oi.id
    LEFT JOIN sub_order s ON i.suborder_id = s.id
WHERE 
(
(oo.update_ts between '2021-04-13 18:29:59' and '2021-04-14 18:29:59' AND oo.create_ts>=current_date-500)
OR
oo.create_ts between '2021-04-13 18:29:59' and '2021-04-14 18:29:59' 
OR
oi.create_ts between '2021-04-13 18:29:59' and '2021-04-14 18:29:59' 
OR
(oi.update_ts between '2021-04-13 18:29:59' and '2021-04-14 18:29:59' AND oi.create_ts>=current_date-500)
)
```

Comment: Redshift doesn't provide much opportunity for optimization.  But my first suggestion is to select only the columns you really want.  Selecting all columns is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your data in more detail and knowing the full query load you want to optimize it will difficult to get things exactly correct.  However I see a number of things in this that are POTENTIAL areas for significant performance issues.  I do this work for many clients and while the optimization methods in Redshift differ from other databases there are a number of things you can do.

First off you need to remember that Redshift is a networked cluster of computers acting as a coherent database.  This allows it to scale to very large database sizes and achieve horizontally scalable compute performance.  It also means that there are network cables in play in the middle of your query.

This leads to the issue that I see most often at issue - massive amounts of data being redistributed across these network cable during the query.  In your case you have not assigned a distribution key which will lead to random distribution of your data.  But when you perform those joins based on "id" all the rows with the same id need to be moved to one slide (compute element) of the Redshift cluster.  Basically all your data is being transferred around your cluster and this takes time.  Assigning a common distribution key that is also a common join on (or group by) column, such as id, will greatly reduce this network traffic.

The next most common issue is scanning (or writing) too much data from (or to) disk.  The disks on Redshift are fast but the data is often massive and the data is still moving through cables (faster than network but still takes time).  Redshift helps this by having metadata stored with your data on disk and when it can it will not read unneeded data based on your Where clauses.  In your case you have where clauses that are reducing the needed rows (I hope) which is good.  But you are using a column that is not the sort key.  If these columns correlates well with each other this may not be a problem but if they do not you could be reading more data than you need.  You will want to look at the metadata for these table so see how well your sort keys are working for you.  Also, Redshift only reads the columns you reference in your query so if you don't ask for a columns its data is not read from disk.  Having "*" in your select is reading all the columns - if you don't need all the columns think about listing only the needed columns.

If your query is working on data that doesn't fit in memory during execution the extra data will need to spill to disk.  This creates writes to disk of the swapped data and then reads of it back in.  This can happen multiple times during the query.  I don't know if this is happening in your case but you will want to check if you are spilling during your query.

The thing that impacts everything else is issues in the query and these take a number of forms.  If your joins are not properly qualified then the amount of data can explode making the two issues above much worse.  Window functions can be expensive especially when a partition different than the distribution key is used but also when the amount of data being operated on is larger than is needed.  There are many other but these are two possible areas that look like they may be in your query.  I just cannot tell by the info provided.

I'd start by looking at the explain plan and the actual execution information from system tables.  Big numbers for rows or cost or time will lead you to the likely areas that need optimization.  Like I said I do this work for customer all the time and can help here as time allows but much more information will be needed to understand what is really impacting your query.